# Disable Sign On Paper button

Tags: docusignapi

How do I remove the sign on paper option? I used the enableWetSign and EnableWetSign options but they do not work.

So how do I do it?

Thanks.

```
"<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
    "<status>created</status>" + 
    "<emailSubject>" + emailSubject + "</emailSubject>" +
    "<EnableWetSign>false</EnableWetSign>" +
    "<requireSignOnPaper>false</requireSignOnPaper>" +  
    "<recipientsLock>" + recipientsLock + "</recipientsLock>" +
    "<messageLock>" + messageLock + "</messageLock>" + /* If true, prevents senders from changing the emailBlurb and emailSubject for the envelope. */
    "<templateLocked>true</templateLocked>" +
    "<recipients>" +
    "<signers>" +
        recipientsXML +
    "</signers>" +
    "</recipients>" +
"</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Comment: Can you include your full request with headers?

Comment: Have you tried using proper camel case for the property?  I see above you have `<EnableWetSign></EnableWetSign>`, what if you change to `<enableWetSign></enableWetSign>`?

Comment: Hi and yes, I have tried both cases. and how do I get the full requests so that I can post them here?

Comment: You can use a tool like Fiddler or any other tool that captures the raw requests that you are sending out.  There's lots of tools out there that will do this...

Comment: Hey EpicDev, I snooped around on my side and I think that this might be a setting that needs to be enabled on your dev account to allow the disabling of signing on paper button.  Send me your account ID in demo and I will enable this option for you.  ergin . dervisoglu [at] docusign . com

Comment: MY accountID is 682691.

Also, tell me which option it is after you enable it so that i can know what you did please.

Answer (score 0):

EpicDev is correct that this is an account setting. You can find it under Preferences>Account Administration>Features. The check box is located under the "Sending and Signing" options.

I would post a picture but don't have the rep yet.

Hope this helps. Please mark as answered if it does!

Comment: Hi, theLitmas, I tried that and that did not work, the button is still there.